# Why does this BNF checker fail when checking specific grammar?

Tags: c

I am trying different scenarios to check the syntax of BNF grammar but when I have input `0 1 0 ; 0` I am getting an output of yes instead of no. The BNF grammar is `A ::= 0 B` and `B ::= 1 A | 2 B | ;` Would another else if statement fix this issue? Below is the code I have written so far. Any help resolving this or understanding how to resolve it is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void A(), B();

// input token
char tok[10];

// return the next token from standard input as a string,
// or return NULL if there is no more input
char *lexan() {
  int n;
  n = scanf("%s", tok);
  if (n == EOF) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return tok;
}

// print an error message and exit
void error(char* msg) {
  printf("%s\n", msg);
  exit(1);
}

// return if the standard input follows the syntax for A,
// else print an error message and exit
void A() {
  char *lookahead;

  lookahead = lexan();

  if (lookahead == NULL) {
    error("no");
  }
  else if (strcmp(lookahead, "0") == 0) {
    B();
  }
  else error("no");

}

// return if the standard input follows the syntax for B,
// else print an error message and exit
void B() {
  char *lookahead;

  lookahead = lexan();

  if (lookahead == NULL) {
    error("no\n");
  }
  else if (strcmp(lookahead, "1") == 0) {
    A();
  }
  else if (strcmp(lookahead, "2") == 0) {
    B();
  }
  else if (strcmp(lookahead, ";") == 0) {
    printf("yes\n");
  }
  else error("no\n"); 
  exit (1);

}

int main() {
  A();
  // the input should be one A only
  if (lexan() != NULL) {
    error("no");
  }
  printf("yes\n");
  
}
```

Comment: If you're advanced enough to be writing parsers, don't you know how to use a debugger? Step through the debugger to see how you're getting there.

Comment: @Barmar The place I have to code on for this does not have a debugger. I am coding this through command line through nano.

Comment: The problem is that you don't check that there are no more tokens after finding a match. So it's matching `0 1 0 ;` and ignoring the extra `0` at the end. You print `yes` when you see the `;`.

Comment: It's like a regexp with no `$` at the end.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, add `printf()` statements in the code. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/